# Как получить первый и последний элемент в Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет подскажите пожалуйста как получить из adr_address первый и последний элемент по названию класса?

Новосибирск, Новосибирская обл., Россия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пробовал получить первый элемент таким образом по названию класса но не получается

```html
console.log(r.getPlace().adr_address.getElementsByClassName('locality'))
```

но вот такая ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
{address_components: Array(4), adr_address: "<span class="locality">Новосибирск</span>, <span c…</span>, <span class="country-name">Россия</span>", formatted_address: "Новосибирск, Новосибирская обл., Россия", geometry: {…}, icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png", …}
utc_offset: (...)
address_components: Array(4)
0:
long_name: "Новосибирск"
short_name: "Новосибирск"
types: (2) ["locality", "political"]
__proto__: Object
1:
long_name: "город Новосибирск"
short_name: "г. Новосибирск"
types: (2) ["administrative_area_level_2", "political"]
__proto__: Object
2: {long_name: "Новосибирская область", short_name: "Новосибирская обл.", types: Array(2)}
3:
long_name: "Россия"
short_name: "RU"
types: (2) ["country", "political"]
__proto__: Object
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
adr_address: "<span class="locality">Новосибирск</span>, <span class="region">Новосибирская обл.</span>, <span class="country-name">Россия</span>"
formatted_address: "Новосибирск, Новосибирская обл., Россия"
geometry: {location: _.L, viewport: _.ee}
icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png"
id: "72530409b791f68a996ff3d0835f10ca2e1f0f8a"
name: "Новосибирск"
photos: (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
place_id: "ChIJl03MkOHl30IRhenT4XMGOps"
reference: "ChIJl03MkOHl30IRhenT4XMGOps"
scope: "GOOGLE"
types: (2) ["locality", "political"]
url: "https://maps.google.com/?q=%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA,+%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB.,+%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F&ftid=0x42dfe5e190cc4d97:0x9b3a0673e1d3e985"
vicinity: "Новосибирск"
website: "http://www.novo-sibirsk.ru/"
html_attributions: []
utc_offset_minutes: 420
get utc_offset: ƒ ()
set utc_offset: ƒ (c)
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: @MaximLensky, нет, там строка html

Comment: Перед использованием getElementsByClassName нужно получить Html элементы из строки

Comment: А точно надо именно из этого поля? Может в объекте где-то есть уже готовые данные?

Comment: @Grundy еще есть тут эти данные http://i.imgur.com/e9Eq87I.png но там иногда меняется последовательно вместо первого нужного значения могуь быть другое что то подобное. Хотелось получать значения из того что выше в заглавном посте

Comment: но годится любой вариант

Comment: Нужно получить текст название города Новосибирск

Comment: и отдельно название страны Россия

Comment: @MaximLensky Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: @MaximLensky обновил первый пост

Comment: видишь какая штука - только дополнил вопрос примером и сразу ответ появился

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var comps = r.getPlace(...).address_components;
var city = comps.find(i => i.types[0] == "locality").long_name;
var country = comps.find(i => i.types[0] == "country").long_name;
```

Comment: всем спасибо! получилось!

Comment: @Vlad Пожалуйста. Успехов.